# Active Class not switching on JS Nav Dots

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav, squarespace

I've been using this [code snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dot-navigation-with-tooltips) to add in a vertical dot nav to a one page site, which smooth scrolls to a section when one of the links are clicked, and keeps a highlight on the active section. I did a lot of tweaking to the css to make it look how I wanted, and then replaced the sections.

For some reason, the active class on the fourth and fifth dots aren't reacting the way they should, and both the fourth and fifth dot are highlighted when you select the fourth dot. Ive tested it on a few devices and they all do the same thing. It works fine on the jsfiddle but the squarespace site looks like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/1f2a2d97d52d7fb109006faca7ed8433.gif), so was hoping someone might be able to help/tell me whats making it misbehave.

[Squarespace link](http://sophie-arnold-gyz4.squarespace.com/oodkasokdoakas-1)

[Jsfiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/tibevr/zma4t3pz/46/), pasted js code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.awesome-tooltip').tooltip({
    placement: 'left'
});   

$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
  dotnavigation();
});

function dotnavigation(){

    var numSections = $('section').length;

    $('#side-nav li a').removeClass('active').parent('li').removeClass('active');     
    var sections = $('section');
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)  {

      var ele = $(sections[i]), nextTop;

      //console.log(ele.next().html());

      if (i < sections.length - 1) {
        nextTop = Math.floor($(sections[i + 1]).offset().top);
      }
      else {
        nextTop = $(document).height();
      }

      if (ele.offset() !== null) {
        thisTop = Math.floor(ele.offset().top - ((nextTop - ele.offset().top) / numSections));
      }
      else {
        thisTop = 0;
      }

      var docTop = $(document).scrollTop();

      if(docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)){
        console.log(docTop + ":" + thisTop  + ":" + nextTop );
        $('#side-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
      }
    }
}

/* get clicks working */
$('#side-nav li').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
      posi,
      ele,
      padding = 0;

    ele = $(id);
    posi = ($(ele).offset()||0).top - padding;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:posi}, 'slow');

    return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance friends

Comment: Hi, could you post your code that's not working in the question.

Comment: @JamesBond thanks, forgot to add it :)

Comment: Did you consider making use of [fullPage.js for that](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)? See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cung265g/2/).

Comment: @Alvaro thanks for the suggestion, ill check it out for sure if I can't get a fix for this little issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your last 2 sections height is not much big to trigger in view port top.
Try to give height max to window height.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry, explain again? :)

Comment: you have tried get if        nextTop = Math.floor($(sections[i + 1]).offset().top); and than you have checked whether it reaches top or not 'if(docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)){'  but if your sections height is not big and not cross doctop your nav will not be activated so increase height of that sections make sure its larger than one screen

Comment: I understand that, but I believe the sections do span more than a screen, if im not mistaken.